# How to delete a Record from a List of files in a model in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi all i have a TextBox and a Fileupload controll and a Table to show the uploaded Files...and i have a delete link in my table..so that user can delete any of the uploaded files before clicking on submit button....for this i have model

```
     public BugModel()
    {
        if (ListFile == null)
            ListFile = new List<BugAttachment>();
    }
    public List<BugAttachment> ListFile { get; set; }
}

public class BugAttachment
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int BugAttachmentID { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentName { get; set; }
    public int BugID { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentUrl { get; set; }
    public string AttachedBy { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

when ever user uploads  a file i keep them in Listfile list and show them in table..now what i want is i want to delete the uploaded file from server and from the Listfile also
..i had succede deleting the file from uploaded files folder ...now i want to remove the AttachmentName and AttachmentUrl from my ListFile also when ever user clicks on delete link..how should i do this..any ideas are much appreciated

this is what i had done till now

```
      public ActionResult Delete(string FileName, BugModel model)
    {

        if (Session["CaptureData"] == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            model = (BugModel)Session["CaptureData"];
        }
       char DirSeparator = System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

        string FilesPath = ";" + FileName;
        string filenameonly = name + Path.GetFileName(FilesPath);
        string FPath = "Content" + DirSeparator + "UploadedFiles" + DirSeparator + filenameonly;
        // Don't do anything if there is no name
        if (FileName.Length == 0) return View();
        // Set our full path for deleting
        string path = FilesPath + DirSeparator;
        // Check if our file exists
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + FPath)))
        {
            // Delete our file                System.IO.File.Delete(Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + FPath));                 
        }            
        return View("LoadBug");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `FileName` is unique, you can create a new List of BugAttachments objects and exclude a particular object with the specified FileName

```
List<BugAttachment> allBugAttachemnts=GetAllAttachmentsFromSomeWhere();

List<BugAttachment> newBugAttachments = allBugAttachemnts.ListFile.
                              Where(x => x.FileName!= FileName).ToList();
```

Now `newBugAttachments`  will have the Items after deletion.

You may also use`RemoveAll` method which updates the original List

```
allBugAttachemnts.RemoveAll(x => x.FileName!= FileName);
```

Assuming `GetAllAttachmentsFromSomeWhere` method returns a List of Available `BugAttachment` objects for the specified `BugModel` and `FileName` is the parameter which has the FileName to be deleted